# Building a Generating Function to Represent an Integer Partition

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

From a Miklos Bona combinatorics textbook,

[image: problem]

I'm at an almost total loss.  My professor recently discussed products of generating functions, so I suspected this problem might relate.  The only strategy I came up with was to find a g.f. for $p_{e} (n)$, that is, the number of  partitions of $n$ into even parts that are at most 6, and a separate one, say $p_{o} (n)$, or the number of ways of partitions of $n$ into at most one odd part, and multiply them.

For $p_{e} (n)$, I obtained $$p_{e} (n)=1+x^{2}+2x^{4}+3x^{6}+...$$
... which seems fishy.  For $p_{o} (n)$, I obtained $$p_{o} (n)=x+x^{3}+x^{5}+...$$... which again I'm not sure if that's quite right.  I truly want to learn to do these types of problems, so any help just getting started would be much appreciated.  Also, sorry for not posting more preliminary work - this thing has me on the ropes.

Comment: Images of text are not very good for search engines. Would you mind typing up the question? You can indicate that it is a quote by preceding the relevant lines with `>`.

Answer (score 2):

The GF for partitions into $2$s, $4$s and $6$s is
$$f(x)=\frac1{(1-x^2)(1-x^4)(1-x^6)}.$$
The GF for partitions into exactly one odd part is
$$g(x)=x+x^3+x^5+\cdots=\frac x{1-x^2}.$$
The GF for partitions into exactly one odd part and other parts in $\{2,4,6\}$
is $f(x)g(x)$ etc.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a shot.